# How can I list the files

Tags: python, sockets

i am new on python. I want to list all the files in the server , on the client. I tried to do but i couldnt.

server.py:

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 5050

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
print('[WAITING FOR NEW CONNECTIONS...]')

conn,addr = s.accept()
print(addr, ' has connected the server')
```

client.py:

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = input(str('Please enter the host address: '))
port = 5050
s.connect((host,port))
print('[CONNECTED]')

list = os.listdir('.')

for i in list:
    if i.endswith('.txt'):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Well, right now, you're reading the files on the client. Also, the server does nothing more than wait for a connection and then exit. But really, you'll first need to define some sort of communication protocol to determine how the server is going to format the data for the client to consume.

Comment: Python already has SimpleHTTPServer module can run it using ``python -m SimpleHTTPServer`` . You can look its code at https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py